# How can I temporarily override the @LastModifiedDate and @UpdateTimestamp annotations?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA project in which one of my model properties has a Date field that is annotated with @LastModifiedDate and @UpdateTimestamp, with the intention being that the date keeps track of when the last modification has been made to that entity.

A situation has arisen in which we need to update a property without updating the last modification date. Is this possible?

I thought I could do it by executing a native query, but this doesn't seem to be working.

I know for sure that the column in the database was not created in a way that the database itself would be updating it automatically. I can directly execute the SQL update statement from a SQL client and see that it updates the column I want without disturbing the modification date.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Not sure why a native query wouldn't work, but you can use Bulk update JPQL queries as well: createQuery("UPDATE Customer c SET c.status = ‘outstanding’ WHERE c.balance < 10000").executeUpdate(); You can pass in parameters to select a single row by id or any query selection. Note though that this bypasses the entity, so your cache and any entity objects representing this data would need to be refreshed to pick up the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried callback methods available in JPA such as @PostUpdate and @PrePersist? A @PostUpdate callback method is a method that is called after an entity is updated. @PrePersist callback method is a method that is called before an entity is persisted.

You could use these methods to update the lastModifiedDate and updatedDate fields, but only if a certain condition is met.